# Add an increasing counter in a PHP table for a shopping cart

Tags: php

I have written a code for shopping cart and wanted to add numbers 1, 2, 3,  etc. before each product in a table.

[image]

How to add counter inside `<th>x</th>`?

Full code of table below:

```
<?php
if ($obj_cart->items) {
    echo("<form action='" . BASE_URL . "products/process/process_cart.php' method='post'>"
    . "<table class='table table-hover' width='650px' border='1px' bordercolor='black' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>");
    echo("<thead>"
    . "<tr align='right'>"
    . "<th>x</th>" //here i want to add 1, 2 ,3 . untill products add. how to add loop
    . "<th>Product Name</th>"
    . "<th>View Details</th>"
    . "<th>Unit Price</th>"
    . "<th>Quantity</th>"
    . "<th>TOTAL</th>"
    . "</tr>"
    . "</thead>");

    foreach ($obj_cart->items as $item) {
        echo("<tbody>"
                . "<tr align='center'>"
        . "<td><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/process/process_cart.php?action=remove_item&productID=$item->itemID'>X</a></td>"
        . "<td>$item->item_name</td>"
        . "<td><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/product_detail.php?productID=$item->itemID' target='_blank'>View Details</a></td>"
        . "<td>$item->unit_price</td>"
        . "<td><input class='box' type='text' value='$item->quantity' name='qtys[$item->itemID]'></td>"
        . "<td>$item->total_price</td>"
        . "</tr>"
        . "</tbody>");
    }
        echo("<thead>"
                . "<tr align='center'>"
    . "<th><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/products.php'><input class='btn btn-default' type='button' value='Shop More' /></a></th>"
    . "<th><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/process/process_cart.php?action=empty_cart'><input class='btn btn-default' type='button' value='Empty Cart' /></a></th>"
    . "<th>"
    . "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='update_cart'>"
    . "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Update Cart'>"
    . "</th>"
    . "<th>Check Out</th>"
    . "<th>TOTAL</th>"
    . "<th>$obj_cart->total_price</th>"
    . "</tr>"
    . "</thead>");

    echo("</table></form>");
} else {
    echo("<label>Your cart is empty</label>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this. You need to add a counter that will track the number of currently displayed product so you may print its value wherever you want:

```
$counter = 1; // initial value
foreach ($obj_cart->items as $item) {
    echo("<tbody>"
        . "<tr align='center'>"
        . "<td><a href='" . BASE_URL // the counter is displayed in the next line
        . "products/process/process_cart.php?action=remove_item&productID=$item->itemID'>" . $counter . ". X</a></td>"
        . "<td>$item->item_name</td>"
        . "<td><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/product_detail.php?productID=$item->itemID' target='_blank'>View Details</a></td>"
        . "<td>$item->unit_price</td>"
        . "<td><input class='box' type='text' value='$item->quantity' name='qtys[$item->itemID]'></td>"
        . "<td>$item->total_price</td>"
        . "</tr>"
        . "</tbody>");
    $counter++; // update counter value on each product
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($obj_cart->items as $item) {
   $counter++;
                        echo("<tbody>"
                                . "<tr align='center'>"
                        . "<td>  $counter  <a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/process/process_cart.php?action=remove_item&productID=$item->itemID'>X</a></td>"
                        . "<td>$item->item_name</td>"
                        . "<td><a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/product_detail.php?productID=$item->itemID' target='_blank'>View Details</a></td>"
                        . "<td>$item->unit_price</td>"
                        . "<td><input class='box' type='text' value='$item->quantity' name='qtys[$item->itemID]'></td>"
                        . "<td>$item->total_price</td>"
                        . "</tr>"
                        . "</tbody>");
                    }
```